# Satellite Assembly, ASP.NET language not changing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, satellite-assembly

I'm converting a project to use a satellite assembly.
I created a new class library (named "Resources"). All of the default resources are at the root level `*.resx`.
Then there is a folder for each culture.

"en/"
with  `*.en.resx`

en-GB/
with `*.en-GB.resx`

I changed the .resx files `Access Modifier` to "Public" and changed these settings.

```
BuildAction: EmbeddedResource
CopyToOutputDirectory: CopyAlways
```

I made sure the `.resx` designers `*.Designer.cs` use the "Resources" namespace.

I added the Class library to an ASP.NET MVC app and in `global.asax.cs` I have the culture being set as needed.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
```

I tried adding the `al.exe` and `Resgen.exe` commands to the post-build event in the Resources class library.

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\Resgen.exe"
>   en-GB/MyResourceFile.en-GB.resx "C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\al.exe" /t:lib
>   /embed:en-GB/MyResourceFile.en-GB.resources /culture:en-gb
>   /out:Resources.resources.dll

Looking inside the MVC apps `bin/` folder there are folders for each language with 3 files:

> MyResources.en-GB.Designer.cs,  MyResources.en-GB.resx,
>   Resources.resources.dll

The root level only has `Resources.dll` and `Resources.resources.dll` but the default language works fine. The second `*.resources.dll` is due to the post-build event.

When I change the CurrentUICulture it doesn't change the UI language. Before moving the resources out of the `App_GlobalResources/` to an external assembly it worked fine (Razor example).

```
@Resources.MyResources.StringIdentifier
```

Looking at the Resource `.dlls` using .NET Reflector these are the differences.

```
Satellite Resources: (Project: Resources)
Resources.en_GB.MyResources.en-GB.resources 
App_GlobalResources: (Project MVCApp)
Namespace.MVCApp.App_GlobalResources.MyResources.en-GB.resources
```

Edit:

After setting the CurrentCulture and UICulture in the `global.asax.cs`, I tested manually retrieving a `ResourceManager` which actually worked and retrieved strings in the expected language.

```
            System.Resources.ResourceManager gStrings =
                new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.MyResources", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("Resources")); // Resources=Project Name
            string test = gStrings.GetString("TestString"); // WORKS IN GLOBAL.ASAX.CS!!!
```

I tried the same test in an MVC Controller, but it doesn't work. So the only place the ResourceManager can be retrieved is the Global.asax.cs.

Oddly enough the same test at the UI level in razor would only return the default cultures text! The cultureInfo is correct, but the ResourceManager only returns the default language in the ASP.NET MVC Razor UI. (This is strictly for testing)

```
    @{  
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        System.Resources.ResourceManager gStrings =
            new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.MyResource", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("Resources"));
        string s = gStrings.GetString("Test");    // DOESN'T WORK IN UI
    }
```

**TLDR version:**

Converting from Resources (.resx) from App_GlobalResources to satellite assemblies.

**The issue at hand.**

I can manually call a ResourceManager for the satellite assembly, using the CurrentUICulture language in `global.asax` and it works as expected, however the same test fails from the UI side and fails in a MVC controller.

The default language works fine, so why doesn't the UI switch languages?

Answer (score 1):

If have recently set up a project where the internaltionalization works correctly more or less like you describe.

https://github.com/Jacco/Perpetuality

I switch the language per HTTP request in OnAuthorize in the controller I use as base:

```
using Perpetuality.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;


namespace Perpetuality.Controllers
{
    public partial class BaseController : Controller
    {
        private CultureInfo GetCultureInfo(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            switch ((string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["language"])
            {
                case "nl":
                    return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
                case "en":
                    return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
                case "pt":
                    return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-PT");
                case "de":
                    return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
                case "es":
                    return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
                case "fr":
                    return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
                case "it":
                    return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT");
                case "jp":
                    return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ja-JP");
                default:
                    return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = GetCultureInfo(filterContext);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = GetCultureInfo(filterContext);

            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

In my project the RESX files are specified differently than in yours:

```
BuildAction: EmbeddedResource
CopyToOutputDirectory: DoNotCopy
```

In my vies I access the strings like this:

```
@Resources.Home.Index.FacebookButtonCaption
```

I did setup nothing post or pre build.

In my project the language is always on the url. That was a user can switch language if no appropriate language was initially chosen.

Comment: +1 for sharing. I use cookies for the language, so the Culture is only set e.g. on login. It will be a while before I get a chance to investigate your application in detail (and whether it actually works for satellite resources), thanks for posting. They are a little tricky and require quite tedious details when used in multiple projects. :)

Comment: I think you need to set the cultures for every request coming in. Getting it from the cookies is fine though. My resources are in a separate library too (I think that is what you mean by satelite?)